# Yii url manager rules - hint needed

Tags: php, yii

Assume, we've website which can be displayed in several languages.
Name for each controller is rewrite to certain language.
For example:

```
'kontakt<a:.*>' => 'contact<a>',
'uslugi<a:.*>' => 'services<a>
'<controller:\w+>/\w+,<id_body:\d+>' =>'<controller>/showBody/id/<id_body>'
```

Url `/kontakt` redirect to `/contact` 'uslugi' to 'services' etc.

Ok, but I'd like to perform that result of parse also through the last controller so as to `kontakt/some_irrelevant_title,5` was directed to `contact/some_irrelevant_title,5`

It is possible in some magic way to achieve that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CUrlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager) module accepts regular expressions for the parameters. So use rules like these and just ignore the rule controller variable (c) in the path:

```
'<c:(kontakt|contact)>/<a:\w+>' => 'contact/<a>',
'<c:(uslugi|services)>/<a:\w+>' => 'services/<a>',
```